# How to approach building an Android app that fetches Facebook data and then processes it on a Django server?

Tags: android, django, facebook

What's the best way to go about making an app where the following takes place:

1. User logs in to Facebook and accepts the permissions that the
   Android app wants
2. The user data is then stored at the Django backend of the android
   app
3. The Android app then fetches the processed data from the server and shows it to the user

I just want to know the rudimentary steps like whether I should authenticate on Android and then send data back to the server or should I let the server use the graph API directly and store the information?

But whatever the approach I would like the user to log in through his/her phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You would use the front end of your app to connect to the Facebook Graph API.

2) Facebook will do the authentication and return the server response (Access Token).

3)Using GET requests with the Access Token you can retrieve information about the current user.

4)You can now store this data on your server.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, I first retrieve the info to the phone and then to send it the server?

Comment: Yes, let the user log into their account via the phone. The server will return you an Access Token. Using this access token you can make requests to Facebook to get information about that user. The server will give you the information to your phone and you can now upload it to your own server.